# Rails 3 with omniauth-google-oauth2 fails behind a proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, reverse-proxy

Works find when accessed directly and fails with

```
Not found. Authentication passthru.
```

when behind a reverse proxy

Comment: There is no fundamental reason why Oauth should fail through a oroxy. It's all about ensuring that there is no URL rewriting, or that any rewritten URL is configured in the api console.

Comment: the problem I have is that rails is now sending localhost as a redirect target to google; I need to try https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2#one-time-code-flow-hybrid-authentication

Answer (score 0):

proxy was adding additional backslash:

```
Started GET "//users/auth/google_oauth2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-28 12:13:34
```

which was not recognized; normal query was

```
Started GET "/users/auth/google_oauth2" for 10.113.163.121 at 2015-04-28 12:26:26 +0000
```

after correcting proxy configuration oauth process still fails unfortunately as client is not correctly redirected + redirection url passed to google is wrong - probably some oauth proxy is needed :(

EDIT: no proxy is needed when it is client who is engaging google first - using so called hybrid/server side flow:

https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow

...but it has its own bottlenecks as discussed below:

https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/issues/122
and
https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/issues/174